# colSpan equivalent for React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, html-table

In HTML, if I want a table element to span multiple columns, I can use the [colSpan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) attribute to state how wide the column should be.

I am creating a React Native application with table view and need to duplicate this functionality. Are there any existing React Native table components which have a similar colSpan function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component

Check out Example 3 in the docs and notice how `flexArr` prop is used to give relative size to column number 2 with respect to other columns.

You could also just use basic flexbox concepts to achieve a table like looking layout yourself https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx

Comment: `flexArr` allows me to edit the width of a single column (based on the linked example), but can it be used to edit the width of a single cell?

Comment: You can use flexArr on each row. Most rows would have one set of flexArr arrays, but a row with a colspan would have a flexArr array with fewer elements. So for example 1,1,1 on most rows, but 1,2 on one row would make the cell in the second column take up the space of the second and third column. I used this approach of summing corresponding flex value numbers for columns to make a colspan prop that works just like HTML (my RowHelper component calls the Row component with a recalculated flexArr).

Comment: @dhruv Parmar, can you help me out in achieving this type of layout.. I tried above library as well . For more info 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74384191/create-table-layout-in-react-native-which-supports-clicks-and-icons-with-nested